# What does 'if type(x) == type(()):' mean?

Tags: python

I across a line of code : 'if type(x) == type(()):', I am not sure what this means.. It is comparing the type of 'x' to exactly what? Any answers are much appreciated,thanks!

Comment: if variable `x` is a `tuple` as `type()` contains `()` which is a tuple.

Comment: `type(())` is a silly way of writing `tuple`, since `()` is a (empty) tuple literal. This should be written either as `type(x) is tuple` or probably `isinstance(x, tuple)`.

Answer (score 1):

`()` is an empty tuple.

`type(())` will give you the type `tuple`.

Its checking to see if `x` is of type `tuple`.

Comment: How terribly unexplicit. Why people don't simply write `if type(x) is tuple:`?

Comment: @Guimoute People should really use `isinstance(x, tuple)` instead. Comparing the type would evaluates to `False` for subclasses, yet they are still valid tuple instances.

Comment: @JordanBrière it really depends on what they do. I usually choose to avoid subclasses (and classes) altogether. You have that freedom in Python.

Comment: A good reason specifically to not match subclasses of `tuple` is that `namedtuple` creates subclasses of `tuple`, but in practice `namedtuple` is often used as a convenient alternative to writing a simple class, in which case the programmer has no intention to use the instances as tuples. My guess is that in real production code, the vast majority of times something is a subclass of `tuple`, it's due to how `namedtuple` is implemented rather than a deliberate design decision.

Comment: @kaya3: `namedtuples` _are_ tuples, so there's usually no reason to differentiate the two. Regardless, even if you wanted/needed to for some (valid) reason, you should use the term `tuple` not `type(())`.

Comment: @martineau I am not defending `type(obj) is type(())` at all. The point I'm making is that `namedtuples` are only tuples in the sense that they inherit from the class `tuple`, and this is usually not an intentional design decision. Programmers usually would not want one of their `namedtuple` instances to be accepted where a tuple is expected.

Comment: Let's say I'm writing a function which takes a tuple of class instances, but also accepts a single class instance for convenience as opposed to writing `(obj,)` to call the function with a one-element tuple. For my function to treat a single instance as if it's a one-element tuple, my first line might be `if not isinstance(arg, tuple): arg = (arg,)`. This line will work correctly when the instance is of `class Foo: ...` but it will stop working when I refactor `Foo` to be a `namedtuple`. I propose that `namedtuple` is *normally* used like this, as an alternative to writing a class.